# Opening Anylogic model in an older version

Tags: anylogic

I have created a model in Anylogic 8.3. Now I want to open this model on a different computer that contains an older version, Anylogic 8.2.3. This, however, does not work, as I am prompted with the fact that the model is created in a newer Anylogic version.

Is there a way to circumvent this issue? 
I am not a system admin on the computer with the older Anylogic, nor does our license cover updating to a newer version of Anylogic (expired in december 2018).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that by opening the `.alp` file of your model with Notepad or a similar text editor. Then:

1. Get your actual AnyLogic build version (open AnyLogic, click "Help" and then "About". You can find your build-version as in the image below
2. replace AnyLogicVersion and AlpVersion with your required values, e.g. something like `AnyLogicVersion="8.2.3.xxxxxxxx"` and `AlpVersion="8.2.3"`
3. save the file and open with AnyLogic 8.2.3

(Note that if you want to open a model in AnyLogic 7 that was developed in AnyLogic 8, you would also need to remove the entire `<RunConfiguration>` section. But this is not relevant in your case.)

[image]

Comment: PS: Please note that I do not know if this is covered by your current license setup, you'd need to check with AnyLogic yourself!

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin. However, this does not work for me. Using my build for ```AnyLogicVersion="8.2.3.201706091033"``` and ```AlpVersion="8.2.3"```, I still get the same prompt.

Comment: See adjusted answer, you might need to invloce your actual build number

Comment: I had already tried using the exact build version, but it does not work. Even if I input 8.2.3 (or for that matter, 8.2.1) at ```AlpVersion```, I'm prompted that it was created with a newer version of AnyLogic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only possible to go back to an earlier AnyLogicVersion by hacking the .alp if the AlpVersion is the same, because it denotes the structure of the XML.  I don't have an 8.4 file handy, but I have, for example, an 8.5.1 and an 8.2.4, and the AlpVersion is 8.4.9 for AnyLogicVersion 8.5.1, but 8.0.4 for AnyLogicVersion 8.2.4.

If the XML structure is different, the newer version of AnyLogic will likely be unable to load the file.  Looking at the two examples of essentially the same model that I've detailed above, there are readily apparent structural differences in the ActiveObjectClass, for example. If there are not too many structural differences, you could try replicating them. I've succeeded in doing that manually at least once, that I can recall.

There are a variety of online tools that allow you to compare the XML schemas of two XML documents, from which you will be able to judge whether a manual hack is feasible.