# Error Running AnyLogic Simulation - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am working on an AnyLogic simulation model that includes a bonsai connector. The simulation was running fine until I updated AnyLogic to the latest version; AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition **8.7.10**.

I am also using the latest bonsai library available in the [bonsai-anylogic](https://github.com/microsoft/bonsai-anylogic/tree/master/connector) repository.

The simulation builds succesfuly, but when I try running it, it shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: X_FORWARDED_PORT
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer.<init>(ForwardedRequestCustomizer.java:73)
at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.SocketConnectorFactory.createHttpConnectionFactory(SocketConnectorFactory.java:113)
at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.SocketConnectorFactory.createSocketConnector(SocketConnectorFactory.java:48)
at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer.ignite(EmbeddedJettyServer.java:108)
at spark.Service.lambda$init$2(Service.java:632)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Seems like they have not updated bonsai yet. I would revert to the previous version of AnyLogic.

Comment: That could be an option, although my model is already saved with the new version, and I don't think I can re-open it with the older version.

Comment: You should be able downgrade your ALP file and use it in the older version again - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372762/opening-anylogic-model-in-an-older-version

Comment: Thank you! I retrieved the older version, and everything is working fine now. In case anyone is facing the same problem and wants to retrieve the previous version, it can be downloaded from:
https://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-ple-8.7.9.x86_64.exe